# trying to move folders from local to hdfs with %20 in it. unable to copy directories

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to move folders from my local system to hdfs which has %20 in it. I cannot change folder names because it is the value of a column and those are created by spark with partition columns while writing file. I need to move them as it is to hdfs and view them in hive / impala table.

Ex:

```
HADOOP_USER_NAME=vishal hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal "/home/vishal/incoming/partition-edit/tableName/cp_sys_name=Change%20Request%20Satisfaction%20Survey/cp_evaluation_method=survey/" /data/files/vishal/managed/asmt_metric_type_orc_sep_29/cp_sys_name=Change%20Request%20Satisfaction%20Survey/cp_evaluation_method=survey
```

executing above command, but it internally treating %20 as space and throwing File not found exception.

```
Error while Inserting data into target: copyFromLocal: `/home/vishal/incoming/partition-edit/asmt_metric_type_orc_sep_29/cp_sys_name=Change Request Satisfaction Survey/cp_evaluation_method=survey/': No such file or directory

java.io.IOException: copyFromLocal: `/home/vishal/incoming/partition-edit/tableName/cp_sys_name=Change Request Satisfaction Survey/cp_evaluation_method=survey/': 
No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try with replacing %20 with %2520
the idea is to replace "%" with the code "%25" and concat with the "20"